# Cannot change target framework of a PCL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, portable-class-library

I'm trying to create a cross platform project in order to reuse most of the code in a Windows Phone (7.5) and a WinRT simple game. I'm trying to use a Portable Class Library, now that there's an official support for async operations inside WinPhone 7.5 projects (Microsoft.Bcl.Async). I'm having issues installing the NuGet Package for the Bcl.Async (cannot find a compatible framework), and after googling around i've discovered that the problem is that i was targeting Windows Phone 7 (not the required 7.5) for my PCL project.

The problem is that if i try to target WinPhone 7.5 i receive this message:

[image: Automatically downgrading to Windows Phone 7]

Why i cannot target Windows Phone 7.5? Is there a way to force that? (Sorry, maybe this is a truly noob question...but i can't find an answer anywhere). Please also note that this is a valid combination of framework, as stated in the msdn guide that you can find here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx.

Comment: So, what is the problem exactly? You can click OK and create PCL and then install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` and work as intended.

Comment: I can't install Bcl.Async in my PCL project due to the fact that i'm targeting Windows Phone 7 (not 7.5),as stated here (please look at Issue 1 here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb.aspx)

Comment: If I try to do that, I don't get that message. Is your VS up to date? (VS 2012 Update 2 should be the most current version.)

Comment: It wasn't updated, but it wasn't the solution. Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution for this problem...and i was the cause =) 
I'm trying to use MvvmCross and Xamarin in order to write a cross-platform code, but i've made some mistakes when i've changed the Profile104 to provide the Mono for Android target for my PCL.
Removing this resolved my issue.

Thanks to everyone for your answers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `async`/`await` in a PCL project that targets .NET 4.5, Windows Store and Windows Phone 8 apps. Because Windows Phone 7.5 support for async is not out-of-the-box and is dependent on the developer machine, you might encounter such issues. My first recommendation would be [updating the SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276663).

You should target Windows Phone 8 instead for it to work by default.

Comment: The whole point of Microsoft.Bcl.Async is to be able to do that.

Comment: You're thinking in the context of out-of-the-box support for async. WP7.5 does not have it.

Comment: No, I'm thinking in the context of using Microsoft.Bcl.Async, which is exactly what the question is asking about.

Comment: You're missing the point as to why the framework version switches.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky I think you are confused or there is a communication gap somewhere.  The point of Microsoft.Bcl.Async is to allow you to use async and await on platforms that don't support it out-of-the box, such as WP7.5.  I wouldn't call it dependent on the developer machine, it's a NuGet package so the dependencies get added to your solution (and can travel with it) rather than requiring some sort of machine-wide install.

Comment: That's not what I was trying to say. You can't use it in Visual Studio 2010 (despite the fact that you can create 7.5 apps with it) because async/await is dependent on C# 5.0 capabilities, therefore VS2012 + .NET4.5 is a required install. The fact that it's a NuGet package does not mean you can install it in any project.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky Yes, you need VS2012 to use Microsoft.Bcl.Async.  It didn't seem like that was part of the question- there would have been different errors if you tried to use it in VS2010.